# Remove Uploaded zip file from lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I upload previously created lambda function to my lambda function to get node module. and i got unexpected issue by it. so i wan to remove. uploaded zip file from my AWS lambda function and get previous state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to your Lambda function and reupload the new zip file

[image]

Comment: can i go to the previous state of lambda function

Comment: Yes use the menu fixed on the top of page : Actions -> Export function

Answer (score 0):

You just need to upload the new zip file which you want to upload