# Remove zip file from AWS Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I linked the wrong file from an AWS S3 to my AWS Lambda Function. I want to delete the file.

[This post is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091910/remove-uploaded-zip-file-from-lambda-function), but I do not know how to reupload the zip file. I want to either replace it, or preferably, remove it so that I can edit the code again using the inline editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using versioning you will need to re-upload the correct version of the code again.

There is no removing the code you have there as this is now your Lambda functions code, any upload replaces this.

For the future take a look at using [versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html) for your functions so that you can ensure that any accidental uploads will not disrupt applications that are using your Lambda function.

Comment: I see... I was trying to replicate a small example, so I didn't bother using versioning (silly me). Is there a way to see the code I had written?

Comment: It will have replaced the function without any versioning as far as I am aware there is no way to retrieve the previous version of the code. Going forward its best to combine version control with Lambda versioning to avoid this :(